# Create a sheet into a workbook without headers ace.oledb

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, ado

How can I create a named sheet without headers - just like the default sheet - via ace.oledb?

The create command for a sheet must be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE [MySheet] (field1 type, field2 type ..., fieldn type )
```

It creates MySheet and always insert (regardless of HDR extended property in connection string or the registry  setting FirstRowHasNames) a first line in MySheet containing field1, field2...fieldn

Basically I don't want a "Table Header" there, I just need to insert values in a newly created named empty sheet.

Comment: The `HDR` is all you should have to change for that not to happen - I've done this countless times before. Can you post your connection string??

Comment: http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/SQLServer/ImportExcelIntoSQLServer.htm

Comment: oleDbConnection.ConnectionString =
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=d:\NewExcelFile.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO"";";
Tried also HDR=YES - I've already stated that in my post - with and without FirstRowHasNames set to 0 in registry...

Comment: What are you going to do with the sheet once you create it? If all you need is an empty sheet, why not Interop? After all, the only way you will be able to interact with an empty sheet is with Interop.

Comment: I'm wondering why are you answering with a question... I stated very clear what I need. And no, "the only way you will be able to interact with an empty sheet is with Interop" is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't pretty, but it's the only way I've found to create a new worksheet with nothing in it. The only problem I've discovered is that Oledb automatically creates a named range on the header cells specified in the `CREATE` command, but assuming you don't care about that then this should work fine.

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName +
    ";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=NO\"";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [MySheet] (<colname> <col type>)";  // Doesn't matter what the field is called
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [MySheet$] SET F1 = \"\"";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: For me, it wasn't dirty.  It turned out that the named range got me around the 255 character limit for `INSERT`s.  if I INSERT INTO the range, then I escape the 255 character limit.